# PHP autoloader issue

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I have a very old application script that actually loads controller, model and entity with the class name using below snippet

```
function __autoload($className)
{   
    list($filename , $suffix) = explode('_' , $className);  

    switch (strtolower($suffix))
    {   
        case 'model':

            $folder = '/model/';            
            $suffix = BIZ_SUFFIX;

        break;  

        case 'dao':

            $folder = '/entity/';   
            $suffix = DAO_SUFFIX;           

        break;      
    }   

    $file = SITE_PATH . $folder . strtolower($filename) . $suffix .'.php';      
    if (file_exists($file))
    {       
        include_once($file);        
    }
    else
    {       
        die("File '$filename' containing class '$className' not found in '$folder'.");  
    }
}
```

Now I have problem in integrating any third party autoloaders, even with the composer autoload.

I have even tried below methods as well

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

and

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

**Error msg:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Template_Model' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `spl_autoload_register`, the `__autoload` function will not be called.

Rename `__autoload` to something else, ex. `old_autoload`. And register it in autoloaders `spl_autoload_register('old_autoload');`

Comment: I have already tried it out, unfortunately it did not work. For example am using swiftmailer, the autoloader of swiftmailer is not loaded instead its loading up my autoloader function.

Comment: remove this part `die("File '$filename' containing class '$className' not found in '$folder'."); ` from your autoloader